# Google charts Axis showing disordered values and columns are suming

Tags: google-visualization

The axis is showing disordered values and the columns are summing I don't know why.

The data is in percentage although it could be more then 100% if the achievement is superior to target.

This is my code (before it there is one Foreach):

```
$vttCloud = number_format((($CountryCloudAchieved)*pow(($CountryTarget*0.25 ), -1))*100, 2, ",", ".");

$vtt = number_format((($CountryAchieved)*pow(($CountryTarget), -1))*100, 2, ",", ".");

if ($vttCloud == 0 && $vtt == 0) {} else { 
        ?>
          ['<?php echo $Country; ?>', '<?php echo $vtt; ?>', '<?php echo $vttCloud; ?>'],
<?php }  } ?>
```

[image: Basically this is my problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use numbers instead of strings for columns 1 & 2 (lose the single quotes)...

`['<?php echo $Country; ?>', <?php echo $vtt; ?>, <?php echo $vttCloud; ?>],`

strange it will let you draw a chart with strings as values,
see following two examples, one with numbers, the other with strings...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChartGood();
    drawChartBad();
  },
  packages:['bar']
});

function drawChartGood() {
  var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'vtt', 'vttCloud'],
    ['Czech Republic', 50, 60],
    ['Italy', 75, 80],
    ['Croatia', 28, 40]
  ]);

  var options = {
    bars: 'horizontal'
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_good'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}

function drawChartBad() {
  var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'vtt', 'vttCloud'],
    ['Czech Republic', '50', '60'],
    ['Italy', '75', '80'],
    ['Croatia', '28', '40']
  ]);

  var options = {
    bars: 'horizontal'
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_bad'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```css
div {
  padding-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>Numbers</div>
<div id="chart_good"></div>
<div>Strings</div>
<div id="chart_bad"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @WhiteHat

Comment: Very very much ! :D